# Why does await triggers the data binding process?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, async-await

I started to use await / async in my WPF application. I realized that a huge number of binding error appeared, though the application works correctly. I spotted the error, the `DataContext` is set too late.
The binding errors appeared when I used the next line:

```
var viewAccounts = await db.ViewAccounts.Where(e => e.ActiveAssetAcount == true).ToListAsync();
```

But if I use the sync version, then the binding errors do not appear (despite the fact the `DataContext` is not set yet).

```
var viewAccounts = db.ViewAccounts.Where(e => e.ActiveAssetAcount == true).ToList();
```

What is the reason for the difference? Is there a way to disable the data binding process until I set the `DataContext`?

Answer (score 1):

Awaiting a method doesn't trigger the data binding process.

Rather than trying to "disable the data binding process until you the set the `DataContext`" you should set the `DataContext` immediately and then set the data bound properties once your async method returns and you have all the information.

Make sure that you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify the view when a property is updated.

Comment: I know that the purpose of `await` is to await the completion of a `Task`. Nonetheless, I have seen that if I use `ToList` there is no binding error, if I use `ToListAsync` there is. Can it be some side effect? (What is more interesting I store the data in a local variable and not in a bound property)

Comment: `ToList()` blocks the data binding and everything else synchronously and `ToListAsync` returns a `Task` that completes eventually. That's the difference.